# How do I fix "bzr: ERROR: Unable to determine your name. "?

Tags: quickly, bazaar

I am trying to `quickly create` my first app and am getting gtk errors when I try to run or create an application.

Here is a copy of what I executed and what results I got:

```
daniel@laptop:~/PyDevelopment$ quickly create ubuntu-application app001
Creating project directory app001
Creating bzr repository and committing
Launching your newly created project!
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `Window' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `App001Window' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
Congrats, your new project is setup! cd /home/daniel/PyDevelopment/app001/ to start hacking.
daniel@laptop:~/PyDevelopment$ cd app001
daniel@laptop:~/PyDevelopment/app001$ quickly design
daniel@laptop:~/PyDevelopment/app001$ quickly rub
ERROR: No rub command found in template ubuntu-application.
Candidate commands are: add, commands, configure, create, debug, design, edit, getstarted, help, license, package, quickly, release, run, save, share, submitubuntu, test, tutorial, upgrade
daniel@laptop:~/PyDevelopment/app001$ quickly run
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `Window' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `App001Window' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
daniel@laptop:~/PyDevelopment/app001$ quickly package
.......Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
.......
----------------------------------
Command returned some ERRORS:
----------------------------------
bzr: ERROR: Unable to determine your name.
----------------------------------
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell bzr what your name is using the `bzr whoami` command, like so:

```
bzr whoami "Jorge Castro <jorge@ubuntu.com>"
```

Substitute your name and address of course. You can see all the whoami options by checking out `bzr help whoami`.

After you've set your name rerun the quickly package command.

And the GTK "errors" are warnings, not errors at all. Lots of applications throw them out for various reasons, but they're not to be interpreted as something serious going wrong.